# Android: RecyclerView, scroll along a path

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make the items within a `RecyclerView` scroll along a path, specifically a curve. At the left and right edge of the screen the offset is 0, and in the middle of the screen the offset is 100% for example. I am attempting to achieve this by setting the Y translation of each view. Currently I am doing this in an `OnScrollListener` attached to the `RecyclerView`. This mostly works OK, but there are occasions where the `OnScrollListener` isn't invoked so the translation resets to 0. These occasions include when adding or removing an item from the `RecyclerViews` adapter.

Is there a better place to attempt to achieve this effect? I have also looked into using my own `LayoutManager` and overriding `OnLayoutChildren`, but again this doesn't work in all cases and isn't called when scrolling.

Comment: Could you please post a code snippet. what are you doing in your OnScrollListener?